# What kind of RGB LEDs are these?

Tags: led, rgb

I bought these RGB flood lights cause I liked the LEDs I saw in them and I was wondering what kind they are so I can just buy the LEDs and not the whole flood light.

[image: Picture of RGB LED]

Comment: Look around the thing for a part number and google what you find.

Comment: No luck finding it which I think is really odd

Answer (score 3):

Usually for stuff ripped out of consumer goods, Alibaba/Aliexpress is the way to go. A quick search here: [aliexpress search for "high power RGB LED"](http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=high%20power%20RGB%20LED&catId=&initiative_id=SB_20140710165329) gives you lots of options, some of which look a whole lot like the LED you pictured. For example, how about [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10W-LED-Integrated-High-power-Lamp-Beads-RGB-300mA-are-made-of-32mil-EPILEDS-30mil-Jingding/1436279051.html) or [this?](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10W-Bright-Light-RGB-LED-Lamp-High-Power-DIY-Chip-Energy-Saving-Square-LED-Chip/1560708708.html)